# Reading a json content in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, json.net

I am new in Xamarin forms and json and I am using the Newtonsoft.Json to deserialze the data

I am trying to read from a json data to a list of a class name user I created.

I am not sure how to connect the deserialize into a a list of class  since after the desrialzation I put it into a var varaible and not to a list of class name users.

will appericate a code example of how to fix my code below:

Thanks.

json looks like this:

```
[{"Id":"0","userPhone":"000000","userName":"Barak","Conferance_ID":"1"}]
```

attaching my code:

```
public async Task<List<User>>  GetUserList(string textBox)
    {
        // Use https to satisfy iOS ATS requirements.
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://conferencecreating-com.stackstaging.com/UsersWebService.php");
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var JsonObject  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (responseString);
           // want to add here how loop the jason object?

    }
```

this the class I created to inset the data

```
 public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string userPhone { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public int Conferance_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var JsonObject  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (responseString);
```

To this:

```
var userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(responseString);
```

To loop over the users, just use a `foreach` loop like you normally would:

```
foreach (User user in userList)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    List<User> Users;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
       try
       {
           string url = "http://conferencecreating-com.stackstaging.com/UsersWebService.php";
           var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
           response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

           var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           Users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(stringResult);
       }
       catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
       {
           Users = null;
       }
```

Make sure you tell the DeserializeObject which Class/Object you want to match. enjoy!

EDIT: Thanks to the Comment from  Sir Rufo I have fixed the Code

Comment: The json document is an array of user objects. Deserialize it to List<User>